# Virtualizor nat translation not working correctly

Tags: networking, ip, vps, nat

So I have vps-server hosted by Hetzner, I have IP range from them and I have Virtualizor as my vps platform. I have problem with IP assignment.My servers ip is 95.216.9.103 and additional IP range is 95.216.233.136 /29. So I have first IP as a gateway and others are part of usable IPs, subnetmask is 255.255.255.0 and Virtualizor nat is checked and Virtualizor network is running. I have interface and I can ping to gateway ip but when pinging vps ip, I get `Reply from 95.216.9.103: Destination host unreachable.`
Here is screenshot of ifconfig:
[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miIl7.png)
enp2s0 is main network and natbr6 is nat for vps servers

enp2s0 interface network script:

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage

DEVICE=enp2s0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=95.216.9.103
PREFIX=32
SCOPE="peer 95.216.9.65"
DEFROUTE=yes
GATEWAY=95.216.9.65

IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f9:2a:998::2/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=enp2s0
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now, I just needed to restart virtualizor main service along with network service